# differentiate arctan (maclaurin?)

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have this assignment: 
Differentiate this expression:

$$ f(x) =\arctan \frac{x-1}{x+1} $$

There is also known that $-1 < x$ (Why is that important?). I do not know how to solve this problem... By using Maclaurin I can come up with this:

$$ f(x) = \arctan (g(x)) $$ 
$$ g(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+1} $$
$$ \arctan g(x) = g(x) - \frac{g(x)^3}{3} + \frac{g(x)^5}{5} + O(g(x)^7) $$

I am confused by the inner function g(x) when using Maclaurin, should I just differentiate g(x) or should I not do that?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What is that you have to do? Is not clear from your question...

Comment: What happens to $g(x)$ at $x = -1$? That's why $x > -1$ is important.

Comment: Just use the chain rule.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the assignment is to differentiate the given expression.

Comment: And what happens to $f(x)$ when $x<-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stating of $x \gt -1$ merely defines a valid domain for inner function so that differentiation is possible, since at $x=1$ we would have a singularity.

Differentiate $f(x)$ using the chain rule, where $$f'(z)=(\tan^{-1} (z))'=\frac{1}{1+z^2}.$$

Thus, if $g(x) = \frac {x-1}{x+1}$, we have by the chain rule: $$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\left[f(g(x))\right]'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)&=\left(\tan^{-1} \left(\frac {x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)'\\ & =\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac {x-1}{x+1}\right)^2}\cdot\left(\frac {x-1}{x+1}\right)'\\& =\frac{1}{1+\frac {\left(x-1\right)^2}{\left(x+1\right)^2}}\cdot\frac {2}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\\&=\frac{2}{\left(x+1\right)^2+\left(x-1\right)^2}\\&=\frac{2}{2x^2+2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Comment: . . . and notice that although the derivative of this function is the same as the derivative of the arctangent function, they may not be the same function.  They would differ by a function that is constant on the interval $(-1,\infty)$ and also constant on the interval $(-\infty,-1)$, and those might be two different constants.  So $\arctan\left( \dfrac{x-1}{x+1} \right) = \Big(\text{constant}+\arctan x\Big)$ on $(-1,\infty)$, and similarly with a possibly different constant on $(-\infty,-1)$.  A trigonometric identity.